# MySQL is handling one SQL query at the time?

Tags: mysql, database

If you got 100 000 users, is MySQL executing one SQL query at the time?

Because in my PHP code I check if a certain row exists; if it doesn't it creates one. If it does, it just updates the row counter.

It crossed my mind that perhaps 100 users are checking if the row exists at the same time, and when it doesn't they all create one row each.

If MySQL is handling them sequentially I know that it won't be an issue, then one user will check if it exists, if not, create it. The other user will check if it exists, and since that's the case, it just updates the counter.

But if they all check if it exists at the same time and let's say it doesn't, then they all create one row and the whole table structure will fail.

Would be great if someone could shed some light on this topic.

Comment: Doesn't MySQL provide a way to generate a unique identifier for a row? If you generate one and use it as a primary key you won't get duplicates.

Comment: in my case its more like.."which user gets first"..the first user will create his row and then noone else will be able to create his own row. so i have to go with "check...if it doesnt exist...create"

Comment: @slaks...the code is very simple...i run SELECT to see if a row with a certain column has been created...if not i run INSERT together with the user_id as the id for that row. so you see..this could lead to 100 000 different rows if they all check the same time.

Comment: Something has to uniquely identify the row that you don't want to duplicate. You need a primary key or unique index to enforce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UNIQUE constraint or, if viable, make the primary key one of your data items and the SQL server will prevent duplicate rows from being created. You can even use the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." syntax to specify the alternate operation if the row already exists.

From your comments, it sounds like you could use the user_id as your primary key, in which case, you'd be able to use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO usercounts (user_id,usercount)
VALUES (id-goes-here,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE usercount=usercount+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put the check and insert into a transaction then you can avoid this problem. This way, the check and create will be run as one one query and there shouldn't be any confusion

Comment: Wrong.  Transactions will also run in parallel, so two transaction will insert two different rows if executed simultaneously.

Comment: Really? Hmm, I didn't realise that! Thanks for pointing that out, I've now learnt something from trying to answer a question...

I think I'll leave my "answer" here though in case there are other misinformed souls like me out there.

Comment: i dont even know what a transaction is=)

Comment: @ajsie, transactions are easy to understand in a relational database context; just like going into a store to buy something, until you pay the transaction can be cancelled (you decide to walk out of the store and not buy the product). In MySQL you can ROLLBACK a transaction; if/when you decide to go ahead with the transaction you COMMIT. Available with InnoDB type db in MySQL.